# C array elements change value

Tags: c, arrays

I define three arrays. Once the first one is allocated, I print out its first element which is as expected. Then, a second array ('problematic') is allocated. When I reprint the first array's first element, it has magically changed to the value I allocated the array 'problematic' with. It gets even weirder. Had I chosen not to allocate the array 'problematic' but 'working' between the two print statements, everything works fine.

What's going on?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int problem(double variable);

int main(){
    problem(1.0);
    return 0;
}

int problem(double variable){

    int limit1 = 10;
    int limit2 = 10;

    double bin_bounds[limit1];
    double problematic[limit2];
    double working[limit2];

    // Allocate first array
    for (int bin=0; bin<limit1; bin++){
        bin_bounds[bin] = variable/limit1 * (bin+1);
    }

    printf("%f\n\n",bin_bounds[0]); // prints 0.2 as excpected
    for (int el=0;el<=limit2;el++){problematic[el]=2.;}
    printf("%f\n\n",bin_bounds[0]); // prints 2.0

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for posting a [mcve]. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: ` for (int el=0;el<=limit2;el++` for loop with <= is almost always wrong. should br `el < limit2`

Comment: That for-loop is not allocating the first array, it is filling the array.  The array was already allocated above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's array out of bound, you are allocating 10 elements with index 0 to 9 but you're accessing index 10. Your loop should only be

```
for (int el=0;el<limit2;el++){problematic[el]=2.;}
```

The big_bounds is probably allocated right after the problematic in this case. So problematic[10] is at the same memory address as big_bounds[0]

Comment: sorry, I messed that up just here. In the original Code both loop boundaries actually have the same value. Edited that here.

Comment: @user6566791 no marcadian is saying you need to change `<=` to `<` in your `for` loop .. `<=` reads 1 element past the bounds of `problematic`

Comment: Thanks a lot - that was indeed the mistake. Somehow did that correct in all the other functions involving the same part and then didn't look careful enough at the faulty one.

Answer (score 0):

Run with valgrind and check whether you are accesing invalid memory.During declaring array init it with 0.